# closing parent process(terminal) doesn't close a specific child process

Tags: bash, command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm new to Linux and so far,I have come to understand that if we open a new process through a gnome-terminal eg: `gedit &` "& for running it in background", then if we close the terminal, gedit exits as well. So, to avoid this ,we **disown the process** from the parent terminal by giving the process id of gedit.

But, I've come across one peculiarity; If we open a gnome-terminal from within a gnome-terminal(parent) with `gnome-terminal &` and now, if we close the parent terminal, the child terminal doesn't close even if I haven't disowned it.

Why is it? And if there is an exception, what is the reason for making it an exception and where can I find the configuration file(if accessible) where this exception has been mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you close a GNOME Terminal window, the shell process (or the process of whatever command you instructed Terminal to run) is sent the SIGHUP signal. A process can *catch* SIGHUP, which means a specified function gets called, and most shells do catch it. Bash will react to a SIGHUP by sending SIGHUP to each of its background processes (except those that have been disowned).

Looking at your example with `gedit` (with some help from `pstree` and `strace`):

When the GNOME Terminal window is closed, gedit is sent SIGHUP by the shell, and since it doesn't catch SIGHUP (and doesn't ignore it), gedit will immediately exit.

```
─gnome-terminal(31486)─bash(31494)──gedit(31530)

[31486] getpgid(0x7b06) = 31494
[31486] kill(-31494, SIGHUP) = 0
[31494] --- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=31486, si_uid=0} ---
[31494] kill(-31530, SIGHUP) = 0
[31530] --- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=31494, si_uid=0} ---
[31530] +++ killed by SIGHUP +++
[31494] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=31530, si_status=SIGHUP} ---
[31486] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=31494, si_status=SIGHUP} ---
```

But when you type the `gnome-terminal` command and there is an existing GNOME Terminal window, by default GNOME Terminal will do something a bit unusual: it will call the factory `org.gnome.Terminal.Factory` via D-Bus, and immediately exit; there is no background job for the shell to see for more than a fraction of a second.

As a result of that factory call, the new window you get after typing `gnome-terminal` is managed by a new thread of the *same GNOME Terminal process* that is managing your existing window. Your first shell is unaware of the process id of the second shell, and cannot automatically kill it.

```
─gnome-terminal(9063)─┬─bash(39548)
  │                   └─bash(39651)
  ├─{gnome-terminal}(9068)
  └─{gnome-terminal}(9070)
```

On the other hand, if you type `gnome-terminal --disable-factory &`, it won't call the factory, and process-wise it will behave just like `gedit` did in your example.

```
─gnome-terminal(39817)──bash(39825)──gnome-terminal(39867)──bash(39874)
  │                                   ├─{gnome-terminal}(39868)
  │
  └─{gnome-terminal}(39819)
```

Closing the first terminal window will close both the first and the second terminal windows.

Answer (score 1):

Running Xfce here but the same probably applies with Gnome terminals.

If I run `echo $$` in both terminal windows [EDIT: and then run `ps faux`] I see only *one* `xfce4-terminal` process but two distinct `bash` processes, which have the same parent: the `xfce4-terminal` process itself. In fact there is only one terminal process that shows more than one window. Bear in mind that one window doesn't necessarily imply one process. Run `ps faux` to see it for yourself.